# Is there a workaround to use Google Books API in my UWP app

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, google-api, google-books

In my UWP app, I want the user to input the title of a book and give the name of the author and the publisher

[image]

The problem is Google Books API says it is incompatible with UWP apps. Is there a workaround?

Comment: where does it says?

Comment: The NuGet package "Google.Api.Books.v1" @vasily.sib

Comment: I have attached a screenshot in the question @vasily.sib

Comment: As I can see [here](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using) you are still able to use api by http requests

Comment: Let me try this @vasily.sib

Comment: It works @vasily.sib. Please post this as an answer so that I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In spite of this Nuget package is not supported on UWP, you are still able to use public HTTP API, as described [in this docs](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using).